# SocketRocket - Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, socketrocket

When trying to connect to a custom socket server using SocketRocket I am getting the error:

```
Error Domain=SRWebSocketErrorDomain Code=2133 "Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response" UserInfo=0x8f6af00 {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response}
```

I have linked this back to the _checkHandshake method in _HTTPHeadersDidFinish. The _checkHandshake method is doing the following:

```
NSString *acceptHeader = CFBridgingRelease(CFHTTPMessageCopyHeaderFieldValue(httpMessage, CFSTR("Sec-WebSocket-Accept")));
```

I have found this question and have the latest version of socketrocket but doesn't seem to be working?

https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/issues/24

Please let me know how I get around this error (SocketRocket - Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept)

Comment: I'm having the same error

Comment: What websocket server are you using? I fixed this issue by forcing the connection between client and server to be through websockets. I'm using a SockJS server so i did that by adding "/websocket" to the url in order to "force" the communication to use websockets. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 10):

I confirm that (using a SockJS server) by changing this:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:9090"];
```

to this:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:9090/websocket"];
```

the error was gone.